# DataStage meta data information

Tags: datastage

I have data stage version 7.5.1.
Now I want to extract meta data information related to all jobs executed in data stage like
job start time,end time,status and failure reason in case of job failure.
If some body can help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've only worked with DataStage 8.5 and I don't what is or isn't available in 7.5.1. With 8.5, there are work arounds I've worked with like After Job Routines where you can output detailed XML reports about the job. From there you can process the XML. Also, look into sequencers that run your jobs and use one of the stages such as the notification activity or command prompt. Use can set options within them to send out emails if the job status fails. Hope this helps a little bit.

Jason

Comment: Good answer what if some one want to write this information in table instead of in file